# Unknown column in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL. I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.car_id FROM cars AS c JOIN customer_cars bb ON bb.age=40;
```

When I run the above query I got the error :

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'c.car_id' in 'field list'
```

Where am I wrong?

(Both `cars` and `customer_cars` tables have `car_id` column)

Comment: That query is incomplete anyway: did you miss something out? Because that error message is not for that query...

Comment: @ gbn, If I know where am I wrong, I wouldn't make this post ... The error is for this query, if you feel the query is incomplete, can you  point out where am I wrong, just answer my question please

Comment: Unknown column ***a***.car_id while your query doesn't even have an `a`.

Comment: @ Tom and @ gbn, that is my typo, I updated the error message, please have a look

Comment: 1. There is no a.car_id 2. Where is the JOIN on car_id 3. Is there a missing WHERE. Your choice: fix the question so we can answer it or argue and watch it get closed while collecting downvotes

Comment: You are also missing a *real* join condition between cars and customer_cars (something like `c.car_id = bb.car_id`)

Comment: Why, please don't close this post, I need help on this... Did I break any rule here??? What is wrong with my post, I mentioned it is my typo for the error message and correct it after realized...

Comment: @Leem.fin: You haven't explained **what** you are trying to do, only **how** you are trying to do it. Not only that, but the error you have included in your question cannot be returned given the (modified) query and data structures as supplied; it therefore looks as though there is some significant piece of information that has not been included.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you simply do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT car_id FROM customer_cars WHERE age = 40;
```

Comment: No, I can't, I know my query is wrong, but I need a query to joint select the car_id. Both cars and customer_cars have car_id column, and customer_cars table has also age column.

Comment: Good point, this gives same answer as OP's *intended* (we guess) query

Comment: @Leem.fin: **Why** do you think you require the join to cars?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with no errors

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cars (car_id INT NOT NULL);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE customer_cars (car_id INT NOT NULL, age INT NOT NULL);

SELECT DISTINCT c.car_id FROM cars AS c JOIN customer_cars bb ON bb.age=40;
```

This with a join condition also works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.car_id 
FROM 
    cars AS c 
    JOIN 
    customer_cars bb USING (car_id)
WHERE 
    bb.age=40;
```

That error isn't for that query...